# I got the address of a large managed object in WinDbg, what next?

Tags: memory-management, windbg

I created a high memory utilization dump and using !dumpheap -stat and !dumpheap -mt  I got the address of two large string generic list of 30 MB each.

I want to know more about these lists. What they contain or which piece of code is using them.

Is there a way to find them out?

0:000> !do 2b370038
Name: System.Object[]
MethodTable: 71e240bc
EEClass: 71c0da54
Size: 33554448(0x2000010) bytes
Array: Rank 1, Number of elements 8388608, Type CLASS
Element Type: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib]]
Fields:
None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get information about the array instances, you can use the `!dumparray` command with the `-details` flag. Be warned however that dumping an entire array may take a while and output a lot of text.

To find out what is keeping the instances alive use the `!gcroot` command. You may also want to check out the `!refs` command from sosex.dll.

sosex.dll also has a `!gcgen` command, which can tell you the generation of the instances. IIRC a corresponding command has been added to the CLR 4.0 version of sos.dll.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you try .Net Memory Profiler (http://memprofiler.com) to explore managed memory dumps. It is so much easier than windbg. A nice GUI that you can use to search and explore graphs of references. You can also see instances' fields' values.